# Exception with background task on Sonar6.5

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using onarQube 6.5 (6.5.0.27846) and after a successful analysis it's time to sonar backgroud task to compute but I encounter this excetpion:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:81)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:82)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.select(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.db.source.FileSourceDao.selectSourceByFileUuid(FileSourceDao.java:44)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.filemove.FileMoveDetectionStep.getFile(FileMoveDetectionStep.java:233)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.filemove.FileMoveDetectionStep.computeScoreMatrix(FileMoveDetectionStep.java:206)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.filemove.FileMoveDetectionStep.execute(FileMoveDetectionStep.java:127)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:92)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bumped into the same issue. It is caused by 'invalid' records in FILE_SOURCES 
table :

- having an already used FILE_UUID
- referencing a project that is not a Sonar 'top project'

Fixed with this query :

```
delete
from FILE_SOURCES
where PROJECT_UUID not in 
(
  select distinct PROJECT_UUID from PROJECTS
  where SCOPE = 'PRJ' and QUALIFIER = 'TRK'
);
```